# Prove or refute contingent: If A implies B is contingent, then B is too

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

The question is:

> If $A, A \to B$ are contingent, then so is $B$

$A, A \to B$ (implies) is a contingent, but how exactly to show «so is $B$»?
If I'm using a truth table, how should I show that $B$ is also contingent?

Comment: What is your definition of "contingent"?  It seems to me that if $B$ is always false, then $A$ can be either true or false, and similarly $A \to B$ can be either true or false (although not independently of $A$, or course.)

Comment: $A$  is contingent if it is neither a tautology nor a contradiction. I also think about contradiction example, my question is more about how to write it formal enough. just show Truth table where $A$ is contradiction, $A \to B$ is contradiction, but $B$ is not? That's all?

Comment: Okay, that's the definition I was thinking of.  So it seems like claim is wrong.  Let $B$ be any contradiction and let $A$ be a propositional variable.  Then $A$ is contingent, and $A \to B$ is contingent, but $B$ is not contingent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not necessarily true.

We explore each of the alternatives to contingency: Suppose $B$ is a tautology. Suppose $B$ is a contradiction. (If both of these lead to contradicting our premises, then $B$ would necessarily be contingent. Otherwise, it is not.

- Suppose $B$ is a tautology (hence always evaluating to true), then
  $A\rightarrow B$ would necessarily be true always...hence a
  tautology. This contradicts one of our premises.
  $\therefore$ $B$ cannot be a tautology.
- Suppose $B$ is a contradiction (always false). This is entirely
  possible, given the contingency of $A$ and of $A\rightarrow B$. That is,
  $B$ could always be false, and then the truth value of $A\rightarrow
     B$ is entirely determined by (contingent upon) the truth-value of  $A$, which is, in
  turn, contingent.
  $\therefore\; B$ **could be a logical contradiction.**

Hence, by definition then, $B$ is not necessarily contingent given only the constraints of the premises. $B$ could very well be a logical contradiction, and in that event, it is not contingent.

Answer (score 2):

Contradiction example:

\begin{matrix}
A & B & A \to B \\
F & F & T \\
T & F & F \\
\end{matrix}

$A$ is contingent, $A \to B$ is contingent, but $B$ is contradiction.